# Representation of tuple set in Pyomo

Tags: tuples, yaml, subset, pyomo

I am trying to solve a problem in Pyomo. I need to write down restrictions on a subset A for some arcs between nodes (I and II) for a Constraint1. I wrote a model:

```
from pyomo.environ import *
model = AbstractModel()

model.I  = Set()
model.II = SetOf(model.I) 
model.J  = Set() 
model.A  = Set(model.I,model.II)

model.c  = Param(model.I, model.J, default=0)
model.b  = Param(model.I, default=0)

model.x  = Var(model.I, model.J, within=NonNegativeReals)
model.y  = Var(model.I, model.II, within=NonNegativeReals)

data = DataPortal()
data.load(filename='Data.yaml')
data.load(filename='Table.tab')

def objective_rule(model):
   return (sum(model.c[i,j]*model.x[i,j] for i in model.I for j in model.J))
model.OBJ = Objective(rule=objective_rule, sense = minimize)

def B_rule(model,i):
  Bb = sum(model.x[i,j] for j in model.J)-sum(model.y[i,ii] for ii in model.II if ii != i)+0.01*sum(model.y[ii,i] for ii in model.II if ii != i)
  return model.b[i] == Bb
model.B1 = Constraint(model.I, rule=B_rule)

def constraint1_rule(model,i,ii):
    if (i,ii) in model.A:
       return model.y[i,ii] <= 10000
    return Constraint.Skip
model.constraint1 = Constraint(model.I, model.II, rule = constraint1_rule) 

instance = model.create_instance(data)
opt = SolverFactory('cplex')
opt.solve(instance)
instance.OBJ.display()
instance.x.display()
instance.y.display()
```

The data is presented in the file Data.yaml:

```
I: [1, 2, 3, 4]
J: [1, 2]

b : {1: 10000, 2: 20000, 3: 25000, 4: 22000}
c: 
 - index: [1, 1] 
   value: 550
 - index: [2, 2] 
   value: 120
 - index: [3, 1]
   value: 650
 - index: [4, 2] 
   value: 550
 - index: [1, 1] 
   value: 120
 - index: [2, 2]
   value: 650
 - index: [3, 1]
   value: 650
 - index: [4, 2] 
   value: 550
```

The two-dimensional set A is presented in the file Table.tab:

```
set A : 1  2  3  4  :=
    1   -  -  +  +
    2   -  -  +  +
    3   +  +  -  +
    4   +  +  +  -  ;
```

After the solution I get the error:

```
Unspecified format and data option
```

How to correctly represent the set A?

Answer (score 0):

First, your data and sets are so small, that I would really consider just putting them into the base file and making a concrete model.  Much easier to troubleshoot.  You could even use basic python to read from csv files or such.

Anyhow.  You can find a good example here on working with .tab files:

https://pyomo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/working_abstractmodels/data/dataportals.html?highlight=.tab#loading-structured-data

2 things you need to do:

1. change your statement for model.A to just show that it is *within* the sets.

---

```
model.A  = Set(within = model.I*model.I)
```

---

2. Clean up your tab file to show the set index in top left and clear out the punctuation:

---

```
I   1  2  3  4  
1   -  -  +  +
2   -  -  +  +
3   +  +  -  +
4   +  +  +  -
```

---

3. update your read statement:

---

```
data.load(filename='table.tab', set=model.A, format='set_array')
```